# Android: Disable Android Beam / NFC file transfer permanently

Tags: nfc, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-beam

I want to disable the  **Android Beam** and **S Beam** permanently. Is there a way to keep the toggle off in the settings of nfc permanently or remove the nfc file sharing capability somehow? My tablet is Samsung Galaxy Tab Active and it is rooted.